# Sympy square root of a matrix - elements are not simplified

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I tried the following operation - square root of a symbolic matrix. I'm impressed at sympy's abilities. If you notice at the end, the square root of the matrix is left in a rather uncanny state - the square roots can all disappear and the elements simplify rather nicely. Is there a way to ask sympy to do this simplification for us?

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c = sp.symbols("a b c")

m = sp.Matrix([
    [a**2 + b**2, 0, 2*a*b],
    [0, c**2, 0],
    [2*a*b, 0, a**2 + b**2]
])

m**(1/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify like this:

```
In [8]: sqrt(m).doit().factor(deep=True)                                                                                          
Out[8]: 
⎡    __________      __________                 __________      __________⎤
⎢   ╱        2      ╱        2                 ╱        2      ╱        2 ⎥
⎢ ╲╱  (a - b)     ╲╱  (a + b)                ╲╱  (a - b)     ╲╱  (a + b)  ⎥
⎢ ───────────── + ─────────────      0     - ───────────── + ─────────────⎥
⎢       2               2                          2               2      ⎥
⎢                                                                         ⎥
⎢                                    ____                                 ⎥
⎢                                   ╱  2                                  ⎥
⎢               0                 ╲╱  c                   0               ⎥
⎢                                                                         ⎥
⎢     __________      __________               __________      __________ ⎥
⎢    ╱        2      ╱        2               ╱        2      ╱        2  ⎥
⎢  ╲╱  (a - b)     ╲╱  (a + b)              ╲╱  (a - b)     ╲╱  (a + b)   ⎥
⎢- ───────────── + ─────────────     0      ───────────── + ───────────── ⎥
⎣        2               2                        2               2       ⎦
```

Declaring the symbols to be positive with

```
a, b, c = sp.symbols("a b c", positive=True)
```

gives this

```
In [13]: sqrt(m).doit().factor(deep=True)                                                                                         
Out[13]: 
⎡a + b + │a - b│     a + b - │a - b│⎤
⎢───────────────  0  ───────────────⎥
⎢       2                   2       ⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎢       0         c         0       ⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎢a + b - │a - b│     a + b + │a - b│⎥
⎢───────────────  0  ───────────────⎥
⎣       2                   2       ⎦
```